# codeigniter inside a php code need to add language type

Tags: php, codeigniter

**this is the code where it load my dynamic menu**

```
<?php echo $this->dynamic_menu->build_menu('1'); ?>
```

**this is the code for my language type**

```
<?php echo lanchor($uri, lang('menuenglish')); ?>
```

**here i wanto to add like this**

```
<?php echo $this->"<?php echo lanchor($uri, lang('menuenglish')); ?>"->build_menu('1'); ?>
```

i know the uper code is wrong but for makeing it clear..

instead of the **dynamic_menu** i wanto to echo from my language varaiables

one of my language variable inside the dymanic menu

regards

Comment: <?= 
$this->lanchor($uri, lang('menuenglish'))->build_menu('1'); ?> you don't want to have an echo in an echo.

Comment: note that <?= = <?php echo shorttag. just change that if you don't use shorttags.

Comment: i know that i can't use echo inside echo that was for making it clear not to use it as code.

Comment: Allright :) i think the answer below will work for you.

Comment: not it's not working but why these people are -marking my question wht thes people problem makeing other reputation down, oof people..

Comment: that's how stackoverflow works. this question is not that good. but i will upvote you.

Comment: Dear @Kees Sonnema if not not good so why some one can't solve it hahaha,,, kiding

Answer (score 1):

Just do this :

```
<?php 
    $menu = lanchor($uri, lang('menuenglish'));
    echo $this->{(string) $menu}->build_menu('1');
?>
```

But if you search for this in Google, you will be able to find the answer.

Comment: Message: Undefined property: CI_Loader::$dynamic_menu

Comment: I forget that you have to put the menu string into a var

Comment: @JoDev, Dear freind same as up error massage, when i use as echo this works fine i see the varaiable is been echod but with the actual code not works

Comment: What does `lanchor($uri, lang('menuenglish'))` will return?

Comment: if i eacho that that returns perfect the variable but if i code that with the code so it not works

Comment: Could you PLEASE show me what `var_dump(lanchor($uri, lang('menuenglish')))` outputs ? (I changed my answer)

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined property: CI_Loader::$dynamic_menu
Filename: layouts/main.php
Line Number: 33